# Windows на систему Mac

Tags: windows, macos

Возможно ли на маке поставить винду не заходя в систему так как (забыт пароль на маке)?

Comment: при включении зайди в режим восстановления и через терминал сбрось пароль

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Сбрасываем пароль с помощью утилиты восстановления

Более сложный способ, позволяющий сбросить пароль для учётной записи любого пользователя при условии, что данные на диске не зашифрованы через FileVault.

1. Выключите Mac.
2. Удерживая клавиши Command и R, нажмите кнопку питания и дождитесь, пока система загрузится в режиме восстановления.
3. Выберите «Терминал» в меню «Утилиты».
   Как восстановить пароль: «Утилиты» → «Терминал»
4. Введите команду resetpassword.
   Как восстановить пароль: ввод команды в «Терминале»
5. Выберите загрузочный диск, если у вас их несколько, и учётную запись, пароль от которой нужно сбросить.
   Выбор загрузочного диска и учётной записи
6. Задайте новый пароль, подсказку к нему и сохраните изменения.
7. Выключите Mac через меню Apple и включите как обычно.
   Выключение Mac
8. Используйте для входа новый пароль.

Источник: https://lifehacker.ru/mac-password-reset/

Comment: Других вариантов нету?